# React hook form useEffect not re-rendering functional component with call to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to do a a react form using react-hook-forms, but I'm having trouble presenting data retrieved from an API call.

I've sort of combined this [example](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/examples/asyncSetFormValues.tsx), which deals with asynchronously setting form values, and this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-nested-arrays-x7btr?file=/src/index.js), which deals with nested arrays.

But for the life of me, I simply could not get it to work. The JSON output of the API is something like this:

```
{"daily": { "last_received_date": "2020-08-03 11:04:18 UTC+8", "tasks": [
  { "id": "1", "freq": "d", "prog": 0, "max": 5, "reward": 1000 },
  { "id": "2", "freq": "d", "prog": 0, "max": 1, "reward": 1000 },
  { "id": "3", "freq": "d", "prog": 0, "max": 3, "reward": 1000 }]}, 
 "weekly": {/*Similar to daily*/}}
```

Here's the functional component:

```
const UserTaskForm = (data) => {
    const [TaskId, setTaskId] = useState();
    const [TaskArray, setChallengeArray] = useState([]);
    const { register, control, handleSubmit, getValues, reset, errors } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = (formData) => {console.log(formData);};

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                let result = await dbGetUserTasks(data.userId);
                console.log(result);
                const tempArray = [];
                const formData = JSON.parse(result[0].challenges);
                tempArray.push(formData.daily);
                tempArray.push(formData.weekly);
                setTaskId(JSON.parse(result[0].id));
                setChallengeArray(tempArray);
            } catch (error) { console.error(error); }
        }

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Box paddingTop={2} paddingBottom={2}>
                <Button type="submit" style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}>Save Changes</Button>
            </Box>
            {TaskArray ? <Spinner animation="border" /> : <TaskTypeCards{...{ control, register, TaskArray, getValues, errors }} />}            
        </form>     
    );
}

export default UserTaskForm;
```

And here's the functional component that calls:

```
export default function TaskTypeCards({ control, register, defaultValues, errors }) {
    console.log(defaultValues); // <--------------- Undefined.
    const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "test" });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(defaultValues); // <--------------- Undefined.
    }, [defaultValues])

    return(
        {defaultValues.map((challenge, index) => {
            return (
                <Card>
                    Blah blah this doesn't work anyway
                </Card>
            )
        })}
    )
}
```

I understand that the components are rendered before the useEffect is fired in `UserTaskForm`, but how do I re-render it, such that `defaultValues` in `TaskTypeCards` don't log out an `undefined`?

Comment: Where in the parent component, defaultValues ?. If it is not passed , it will definetly be undefined. WHat I am missing ?

Comment: In your call to TaskTypeCards you are not passing the prop defaultValues so as @simbathesailor said it is going to be undefined.

Comment: Oh damn, guess I missed that. I thought it would sort of map to that variable name. @simbathesailor, would you mind adding that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: ok Thanks I will add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`defaultValues` need to be passed as the props , to receive it as props in the TaskTypeCards components.

Thanks